# Stripe Webhook - Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: stripe-payments

I just integrated the stripe webhook in node.

I am able to implement simple webhook endpoint and it is working absolutely fine.

But if I tried "Check webhook signature" I am getting the error: " Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

My code looks just as provided by stripe:

```
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
let event;
try {
  event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  // event = request.body;
} catch (err) {
  response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
}

// Handle the event
switch (event.type) {
 case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
  const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
  console.log('PaymentIntent was successful!');
  break;
 default:
  console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  // Unexpected event type
  return response.status(400).end();
}

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({ received: true });
});
```

I am not getting anything in the "event"

Please help me!!!

Comment: What line is the error coming from? What is the output when you print out the event after the signature verification?

Comment: @karbi when I log event inside try-catch nothing was printed out. After try catch its undefined.

Comment: you forgot endpointSecret?

Comment: @Thiha no it is there and I see all the values when I log(request.body, sig, endpointSecret)

Comment: What version of node are you using and do you have the line `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in your code somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`bodyParser.raw({type: '*/*'})`

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/331

My issue was that I'm using NextJS and

> I'm using Stripe to power the payment gateway of a Next.js app and got to the step to verify the webhook signing secret. I had some issues at first because Stripe expects the raw request body whereas Next.js parses the request body before it's passed to the handler.

https://maxkarlsson.dev/blog/2020/12/verify-stripe-webhook-signature-in-next-js-api-routes/